# How to Convert List of List to List of Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a repository that execute a query and returns a list of list according to given parameters. I want to convert this list of list to list of object.

Now here is my repository:

```java
    @Repository
    public class AlarmDynamicSelection {

      private EntityManagerFactory emf;

      @PersistenceUnit
      public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
      }

      public List<Object> alarmSelection(List<String> fields, Map<String, Object> filters){
        EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Object> criteria = builder.createQuery( Object.class );
        Root<ActiveAlarm> root = criteria.from( ActiveAlarm.class );
        root.join("alarmClass", JoinType.LEFT);
        root.join("networkElement", JoinType.LEFT);

        List<Selection<?>> selectList = new LinkedList();
        for (String item : fields) {
          selectList.add(root.get(item));
        }

        criteria.multiselect(selectList);

        ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (filters.get("details") != null) {
          predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get("details")), "%" + filters.get("details").toString().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        }
        if (filters.get("networkElement") != null) {
          predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.join("networkElement").get("label")),
              "%" + filters.get("networkElement").toString().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        }

        criteria.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        List<Object> results = em.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();  

        return results;
      }
    }
```

The parameters are:

```
    "fields": ["id", "details", "networkElement"], 
    "filters": {"id":[312,34], "details":"a" }
```

The result that return from the repository:

```
    [
        [
            123,
            "adasd",
            {
                "id": 20,
                "label": "test"
            }
        ],
        [
            34,
            "dfakrgfA",
            {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "net"
            }
        ],
        [
            312,
            "dgfsesadfsafdf",
            {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "net"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

I would like to change the above result as below:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "details": "adasd",
        "networkElement": {
          "id": 20,
          "label": "test"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "details": "dfakrgfA",
        "networkElement": {
          "id": 1,
          "label": "net"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 312,
        "details": "dgfsesadfsafdf",
        "networkElement": {
          "id": 1,
          "label": "net"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Object keys must come from `field` parameter

Comment: Here you are using criteria query, you can use Projection queries. Where you can directly populate data in the DTO objects. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: It looks like you want to convert `ActiveAlarm` into an JSON format. Use a proper library for that

Comment: Can I use dynamic field selection `criteria.multiselect(selectList);` when I do that? @GauravJeswani @XtremeBaumer

Comment: @Furkan Why do you need dynamic field selection? If it's necessary it's better to specify concrete type of object. Than you have null values in not selected fields. If you don't want to return these null value fields, than probably you should configure your object to json mapper so that it doesn't add null values.

Comment: @oputky I need dynamic field selection because I want to give ability to user that he can personalize his dashboard. He should be able to choose the fields he wants to see. And I want to keep theese options in db.